# Page not scaling to fit the viewport on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport, scalable

My page is not scaling to fit the viewport of mobile device even though I have put the meta tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device- 
    width, initial-scale=1"> in the <head>.
```

When the page loads, the page is too large and does not fit the screen.
css for body is

```
body, html {
position: relative; 
display: block;
height: auto; 
width: 100%;
max-width: 1650px;
min-width: 400px; 
min-height: 650px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: `min-width: 400px; ` could be the issue. remove it and test.

Answer (score 2):

Try a media query with `max-width: 100%` and `min-width: 100%` property like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body,html {
   max-width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will give it a try!